Could Pilate (being the governor) fulfill prophecy by officially declaring Jesus "king of the Jews"?
A governor's job is to appoint other officials to various offices, and their notary makes such things official. Writing in three languages would avoid the need to agree on one language in which to write the affidavit notarizing that Jesus was King of the Jews.
Did writing "king of the Jews" on the sign hung above Jesus when He was crucified serve to officially designate Jesus as such?

James, I've tried to make sense of your question and repair the spelling/grammar errors without changing what's being asked, but it wasn't very clear what you intent was. Please take a look at the edit.

@Matthew I take the question to be: By writing "Jesus of Nazareth King of the Jews" did Pilate exercise his authority as a Roman governor to officially declare (or appoint) Jesus to be King of the Jews? (I would first ask the subsidiary question whether Roman governors had any such authority.)

@AndreasBlass, yes, and I think that's consistent with my edit.

This would be better asked on a history forum, since it's nothing to do with Christianity, except that I think you'd be laughed at for suggesting that a Roman governor would be intending to make a person he was crucifying a king

The question doesn't really make sense.
First, Jesus wasn't claiming to be King of the Jews in a secular sense, or in any sense in which Pilate would have the authority to appoint him. Even if, for some bizarre reason, Pilate had decided to appoint him to a secular kingship over the Jewish nation, that wouldn't achieve what Jesus was trying to do. Pilate has no authority to appoint Jesus to the kind of spiritual kingship that Jesus was claiming.
Second, there was no Roman position of "King of the Jews". Roman governerships and kingships were over territory, not people. Even if he had (strangely) appointed Jesus king of the mainly-Jewish provinces that would not have made him king of all Jews.
Thirdly, appointment never work like that. In order to make someone a king or governor you have to tell the people affected by it (lesser officials, people in general) that this is what happened. Writing a notice on a cross doesn't count. It's pretty obvious that nobody actually took the notice as an actual intent to make Jesus a secular king. Making someone a king isn't about writing a magic formula somewhere and not telling anybody.
Fourthly, if Pilate had intended to make Jesus a secular king in the province of Judea, that would have displaced the other people who previously held the positions,  such as Herod. Then when Jesus died (a matter of hours later) there would have been nobody occupying those positions and Pilate would have had to appoint others to the position. There is absolutely no evidence that he did this.
So no, nothing Pilate did indicated that he intended to make Jesus a secular king.

+1, but - "Jesus wasn't claiming to be King of the Jews in a secular sense" - Jesus absolutely did claim to be the heir of David, and therefore the rightful king of the Jews in every sense. Of course the validity of that claim is completely independent of Pilate (who I doubt had any authority to appoint a secular king of the Jews even if he wanted to).

No. He specifically said not. He said "My kingdom is not of this world."

Whether or not Pilate had authority to appoint a King it is clear from the biblical text that this is not what happened.

Then Pilate entered into the judgment hall again, and called Jesus, and said unto him, Art thou the King of the Jews? Jesus answered him, Sayest thou this thing of thyself, or did others tell it thee of me? Pilate answered, Am I a Jew? Thine own nation and the chief priests have delivered thee unto me: what hast thou done? Jesus answered, My kingdom is not of this world: if my kingdom were of this world, then would my servants fight, that I should not be delivered to the Jews: but now is my kingdom not from hence. - John 18:33-36

Pilate directly asked Jesus if he was the king of the Jews.  Jesus does not deny kingship outright but he does deny earthly kingship.  This is the beginning to Pilate becoming increasingly troubled.  Jesus is scourged by Pilate's soldiers and mocked by them with a crown of thorns; "Behold, the king of the Jews!" they cry as they strike him.  This is not an actual coronation but a mockery.

Then came Jesus forth, wearing the crown of thorns, and the purple robe. And Pilate saith unto them, Behold the man! When the chief priests therefore and officers saw him, they cried out, saying, Crucify him, crucify him. Pilate saith unto them, Take ye him, and crucify him: for I find no fault in him. The Jews answered him, We have a law, and by our law he ought to die, because he made himself the Son of God. - John 19:5-7

At first Pilate presents Jesus, now bloody and mockingly dressed as a king, as "the man" and the Jews want him dead because he made himself the Son of God.  As an aside, this is important!  The Jews understood Jesus to be claiming Divine equality with God!  Pilate then has a conversation with Jesus following which he sought to release him.

And from thenceforth Pilate sought to release him: but the Jews cried out, saying, If thou let this man go, thou art not Caesar's friend: whosoever maketh himself a king speaketh against Caesar. When Pilate therefore heard that saying, he brought Jesus forth, and sat down in the judgment seat in a place that is called the Pavement, but in the Hebrew, Gabbatha. And it was the preparation of the passover, and about the sixth hour: and he saith unto the Jews, Behold your King! But they cried out, Away with him, away with him, crucify him. Pilate saith unto them, Shall I crucify your King? The chief priests answered, We have no king but Caesar. - John 19:12-15

Notice that the Jews wanting Jesus to be crucified were now saying that Jesus made himself out to be king.  They did this in order to apply pressure to Pilate (If thou let this man go, thou art not Caesar's friend).
Pilate is not trying to appoint a king over the Jews.  It is plainly stated in the text (v. 12) that he is seeking to release Jesus and the murderous Jews will not relent.  When Pilate writes "Jesus of Nazareth, the King of the Jews", having already washed his hands of the matter, it is in mockery:  Very likely mockery of the Jews, who had just claimed to have no king but Caesar.

No because Herod already knew the prophecy concerning Jesus , his scribes had informed him in advance that the Messiah was to be born in Bethlehem and that his destiny was to be king over the Jews. This perplexed Herod and he knew no peace and that is why he tried to kill Jesus when he was an infant. Years pass and Jesus is now an adult, Herod has heard all the news concerning what Jesus has been doing:-raising the dead, restoring sight to the blind, walking on water etc., Jesus is before him in chains, this statement that Herod makes is a mockery of Jesus because he knows the crowd will think what king of the Jews(Messiah) would be brought in chains to Herod?, which was the primary basis why the Jews rejected Jesus. They expected an earthly king which was contrary to what Jesus was, a spiritual king.
